# Is there some significant change on BigQuery API

Tags: google-bigquery

Two Months ago, I wasrunning my following codes very well, but now,after I pip install google.cloud again, it is said : 'TableReference' object has no attribute "exists" , and either I can NOT use Dataset.name, it gone as well . so is there any big change about API sounds like I need to restructure my codes...

```
def createTable(client, ds, tb):
    dataset = client.dataset(ds)
   #assert not dataset.exists()
    table = dataset.table(tb)
    #assert not table.exists()
    if not table.exists():
        assert not table.exists()
        table.schema = (bigquery.SchemaField('Name', 'STRING'),
                        bigquery.SchemaField('Age', 'INTEGER'),
                        bigquery.SchemaField('Weight', 'FLOAT'),)
        table.create()
    else:
        print 'this table already existed in this dataset'
        assert table.exists()
```

Comment: Check whether or not your have turned on/turned off legacy mode without your knowledge.

Comment: I was reference to the codes :https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/snippets.py  It doesn't include use_legacy_sql ? and not sure if you  mean this , but this is about API,not understand why we need to add legacy mode?

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't updated in a while, and you've brought in the breaking changes from `0.28.0`, in particular:

> Remove table.exists() (#4145)

and

> Functions to create, get, update, delete datasets and tables moved to
>   the client class.

See:

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/releases/tag/bigquery-0.28.0
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration

In summary, you'll either need to migrate/port your code, or remain on an older version.